OLS Regression transformation where the sum of the independent variables is part of the dependent variable
I recently saw a regression of the following form (not in a book, but more in an amateur setting), with ID $i$ and region $j$:
$$\ln\left(\dfrac{1+y_i}{1+\sum_{j\in\{1,2,3\}}x_{ij}}\right) = \ln(1+x_{i1})\beta_1+\ln(1+x_{i2})\beta_2+\ln(1+x_{i3})\beta_3+\epsilon_i\\
=\boldsymbol{X}_i\boldsymbol \beta+\epsilon_i$$
Now, the ratio $y_i/\sum_{j\in\{1,2,3\}} x_{ij}$ has a certain interpretation, let's call that the $\textit{multiplier}$.
We want to predict for a given $x_1,x_2,x_3$, the $\textit{multiplier}$, $\widehat{\textit{multiplier}}$. This is done in the following way:
$$\widehat{\textit{multiplier}}_i=\exp\left(\boldsymbol{X}_i\hat{\boldsymbol \beta}\right)\times\dfrac{ \left(1+\sum_{j\in\{1,2,3\}}x_{ij}\right)-1}{\sum_{j\in\{1,2,3\}}x_{ij}}.$$
I sort of get the idea of this regression. However, I have the following critiques:

We have the $x_{ij}$s as given, therefore it does not make sense to me to have the $x_{ij}$ as part of the dependent variable. Can someone verify that this does not make sense?
$\textbf{Edit}$: And it seems to me that we introduce an extra source of variability. Can't we just rewrite the equation for all $x$'s to be on the right-hand side?


In the prediction, the left-hand-side of the above regression is then predicted as follows: $$\hat{Y}_i=\ln\left(\dfrac{1+\hat{y}_i}{1+\sum_{j\in\{1,2,3\}}\hat{x}_{ij}}\right),$$ Ofcourse, we do not predict the individual $\hat{y}_i$s and $\sum_{j\in\{1,2,3\}} \hat{x}_{ij}$s, we predict a ratio of these as transformations. Does it make sense to cancel the denominator of the predicted $\exp\left(\boldsymbol{X}_i\hat{\boldsymbol \beta}\right)=\dfrac{1+\hat{y}_i}{1+\sum_{j\in\{1,2,3\}}\hat{x}_{ij}}$ with the observed $\left(1+\sum_{j\in\{1,2,3\}}x_{ij}\right)$s?

Could someone please help me out?
$\textbf{Edit 2:}$
The problem seems quite comparable, I think, as when you run a regression of the form:
$$\dfrac{y_i}{x_i} = x_i\beta+\epsilon_i$$ over $i$.
It would be not correct to do
$x_i\hat{\beta}\times x_i=\hat{y}_i$ I believe.
Furthermore, you can always rewrite the regression above to $y_i=x_i^2
\beta+\epsilon_i^*$, right?
$\textbf{Edit 3}$:  I will be a bit more explicit about the data:
We are considering insurance data, where we are compensated for Expected Losses by Expected Returns. Of course we would expect Expected Returns $\geq$ Expected Losses, otherwise, we wouldn't underwrite the contract.
The $x$-values are expected losses of an contract $i$ per region $j$ as $\%$ (positive) of the insured amount (they are aggregated contracts), the $y$-values are expected returns as $\%$ (positive) of the insured amount.
I find it hard to think about using an offset in this situation. Furthermore, the relation between $\sum_j x_{ij}$s and $y_i$s looks like an upper triangle where $y_{i}\geq \sum_j x_{ij}$ for each $i$.

You might find it helpful to simplify the notation.  Your model can be expressed as $z = x\beta + \epsilon$ where $z$ is a function of the original $y$ and the explanatory variables $x.$ You wish to estimate a function of $x$ and $\beta,$ which you do by plugging $\hat \beta$ into that function.  (Presumably $\hat\beta$ is the ordinary least squares estimate, but even that detail doesn't matter a lot.) This ought to answer several of your questions immediately and point you in the direction of an effective analysis (you want to propagate the uncertainty in $\hat \beta$ through that function).

Thanks @whuber! I will think about that! It is just that I've never seen a regression in where the dependent variable is partly dependent on the independent variable.

There are plenty of examples here on CV--but it's hard to search for them.  One standard form of such partial dependence is known as an "offset," so consider searching for that.

You can rewrite the equations in all sorts of ways, e.g. with the $x_i$ on one side, but it also influences how the error terms are incorporated in the model. You seem to be ignoring this, e.g. when going from y/x = bx + e to y = bx^2 + e instead of  y = bx^2 + ex. From the outside it is difficult to say whether you can do this. The nature of the error terms is unknown to us. ---- So, it is better to start describing in words what is going on. This $\epsilon_i$ what is it, where does it come from, what sort of random error/variability are you considering?

These $x_i$'s what is their value? Are they very close to zero, like $|x_i| \ll 1$? In that case you can approximate the multiplications as summations $$(1+x_1)^{b_1}(1+x_2)^{b_2} \approx 1 + b_1x_1+b_2x_2$$ Also, how do you get this powerlaw behaviour, what sort of process is this?

So, to tackle a regression like this and make the equations easier, there are all sorts of considerations and decisions. The story behind the equations is important here. Statistics is like writing stories with numbers and equations. Unless the steps are trivial, when the story is unknown, then you can't translate numbers and equations into a different representation.

"The -values are risk contributions of an investment  per region . All values (both the s as the s) are denoted in percentages." Doesn't this mean that we have $\sum_{j \in {1,2,3}} x_j = 1$?

Sorry, @SextusEmpiricus. Clarified.

"are expected losses of an investment i
per region" The $x$ are negative, or can they also be positive and expected profits instead of  expected losses.

I am confused now about the meaning of the $x$. You have been using two different things, "expected losses/profit of an investment" and "risk contributions of an investment". In order to get it more clear what is going on, I advise to step away from mathematical equations for a moment, and explain in words what it going on.

Even when I am ignoring the error, $$\ln\left(\dfrac{1+y_i}{1+\sum_{j\in{1,2,3}}x_{ij}}\right) = \ln(1+x_{i1})\beta_1+\ln(1+x_{i2})\beta_2+\ln(1+x_{i3})\beta_3+\epsilon_i\
=\boldsymbol{X}_i\boldsymbol \beta$$ ,then I can't make sense of the original formula and why it is what it is.

@SextusEmpiricus, I tried to improve my question. Is it more clear now? we are considering a dependent variable $y$ and independent variables $x$s which are all bounded from below starting from 0%.

If there is a theoretical justification or measurement-validity argument to support the use of the variable $\frac{1+y}{1+\sum_j x_j}$ or the logarithm of this ratio (I’ll drop the $i$ index for now), then your equation is perfectly reasonable.  However, the analysis of this as a regression with the $\ln(·)$ transform adds a small complication.
In response to the first query, yes...you can write the regression with all the expressions involving the independent variables on one side:
$$\begin{align}\ln\left(\frac{1+y}{1+\sum_j x_j}\right) & = \sum_j \ln\left(1+x_j\right)\beta_j + \varepsilon \\
\ln\left(1+y\right) - \ln\left(1+\sum_j x_j\right) & = \sum_j \ln\left(1+x_j\right)\beta_j + \varepsilon \\
\ln\left(1+y\right) & = \ln\left(1+\sum_j x_j\right) + \sum_j \ln\left(1+x_j\right)\beta_j + \varepsilon \\
\ln\left(1+y\right) & = \ln\left(1+\sum_j x_j\right)·\beta_0 + \sum_j \ln\left(1+x_j\right)\beta_j + \varepsilon \\
\end{align}$$
where $\beta_0$ is constrained to be the value 1.
This is a perfectly reasonable regression model to run (with the coefficient restriction as indicated).  And in this case, the easiest way to run that regression—say in R—would be to use the original formulation (with the expression involving all of the independent variables on the left-hand side).
Assuming you obtain a reasonably well-fitting model, then the answer to the second query is also yes...you would need to use the transformation of the aggregated independent variables to solve back for the predicted value for $y$.  (The tricky part here is that you can easily obtain the predicted value, since $\varepsilon=0$, but obtaining a prediction interval will be a little trickier.)
As for your 2nd edit...I'm not sure the rationale that is relating
$$\ln\left(\frac{1+y}{1+x}\right) = \ln(1+x)\beta_1 + \varepsilon$$
to
$$\frac{y}{x} = x\beta_1 + \varepsilon$$
The first of these is equivalent to
$$1 + y = (1+x)^{1+\beta_1}$$
whereas the second is equivalent to
$$y = x^2 \beta_1$$
(an example of the different estimation results for power functions vs. polynomial functions).
Hope this helps...happy to clarify more if requested.

Hi @Gregg H, thank you for your answer. Could you please explain why you can obtain the predicted value for $y$, since $\epsilon = 0$: Why can you do $\exp\left(X\hat\beta\right)\times (1+\sum_j x_{ij}) = \tfrac{1+\hat y_i}{1+\hat x_{ij}}\times (1+\sum_j x_{ij}) =1+\hat y_i$  as $\epsilon=0$?

If you drop the error term from the model, you obtain the predicted value (or better, the conditional mean of $y$ given your $X$).  Then you should be able to just plug in your values for $X$ and solve for $y$.

Sorry @gregg h, still not clear to me. Why does the second equality term in my previous comment hold true?

$$\ln(1+y) = \ln(1+\sum x) + \sum \ln(1+x_i)\beta_i + \varepsilon$$ $$\ln(1+y) = \ln(1+\sum x) + \sum \ln(1+x_i)\beta_i$$ $$\ln(1+y) = \ln((1+\sum x) \prod (1+x_i)^{\beta_i})$$ $$1+y = (1+\sum x)\prod (1+x_i)^{\beta_i}$$

I can understand the basic algebra. However, it gives no explanation why you cancel the predicted x's on the lhs with the observed x's. That is $\tfrac{1+ \hat y_i}{1+\sum\hat x_i}\times \left(1+\sum x_i\right)=(1+\hat y_i)$, see my second point in the original question.

I'm sorry...but I don't know what you mean by "cancel the predicted x's" on the lhs"...with a constrained regression model, there are actually no x's (transformed or otherwise) on the lhs.

I understand now. Thanks
